# Conversion of String to JComboBox

Tags: java, string, model, jcombobox

How do I convert `string to JComboBox object model` ?

Note: Im using **NetBeans IDE 8.0.2**

Answer (score 1):

to change `JComboBox` from `<String>` to `<Object>`

1. right click on `JComboBox` and select properties
2. select code tab
3. click on ... button from type parameters
4. replace `<String>` to `<Object>` and click ok.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You don't convert a String to a ComboBoxModel. You add the String to the combo box or the ComboBoxModel.

For example:

```
JComboBox<String> comboBox = new JComboBox<String>();
comboBox.add( "One" );
comboBox.add( "Two" );
comboBox.add( "Three" );
```

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Combo Boxes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html) for more information and other examples.

You can also search the forum or web for other examples.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem.

I needed to be able to grab each line independent of the other so I can use just one Text file but break it out to different j combo boxes. Below was what I did. Is there a shorter way of doing this? I will have 20 JComboBox with each having around 7 select entries. The entries for the drop down boxes are around 50 lines of selections.

```
public void inputFile() throws IOException{

    //File reader method

    FileReader file = new FileReader("c:\\jcboEntries.dat");
    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(file)) {

         String[] lines = new String [6];
         String [] jcbo = new String [6];
         try {

            int i =0;
            lines[0] = br.readLine();
            jcbo[0] = lines[0];
            jcbo0 = jcbo[0];
            jcboNUMONE.addItem(jcbo0);
            System.out.println(jcbo0);

            lines[1] = br.readLine();
            jcbo[1] = lines[1];
            jcbo1 = jcbo[1];
            jcboNUMONE.addItem(jcbo1);
            System.out.println(jcbo1);

            lines[2] = br.readLine();
            jcbo[2] = lines[2];
            jcbo2 = jcbo[2];
            jcboNUMONE.addItem(jcbo2);
            System.out.println(jcbo2);

            lines[3] = br.readLine();
            jcbo[3] = lines[3];
            jcbo3 = jcbo[3];
            jcboNUMONE.addItem(jcbo3);
            System.out.println(jcbo3);

            lines[4] = br.readLine();
            jcbo[4] = lines[4];
            jcbo4 = jcbo[4];

            jcboNUMONE.addItem(jcbo4);
            System.out.println(jcbo4);

            lines[5] = br.readLine();
            jcbo[5] = lines[5];
            jcbo5 = jcbo[5];
            jcboNUMONE.addItem(jcbo5);
            System.out.println(jcbo5);


         } catch (IOException e){}

     } catch (IOException e){}    

}
```